# Get the max field value from each row

Tags: sql-server

How Can I get the max value from few columns for each table row?

```
ID          Date1      Date2      
----------- ---------- ---------- 
1           2019-01-01 2019-12-29
```

result:

```
ID          MaxDate   
----------- ---------- 
1           2019-12-29
```

Comment: How is `'Avraham'` "greater than" `'Yaakov'`? `'Avraham'` has the lowest value of those names, not the greatest.

Comment: 'A' is Great than 'Y'

Comment: @Michal for the names you only compare with the first letter ?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6460f/3)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (ID int,Date1 date,Date2 date)
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID,Date1,Date2) VALUES ('1','2019-01-01','2019-12-29')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    ID,CASE
        WHEN Date1 >= Date2   THEN Date1
        WHEN Date2 >= Date1 THEN Date2
ELSE   Date1
    END AS MaxDate

    FROM MyTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6460f/3/0)**:

```
| ID |    MaxDate |
|----|------------|
|  1 | 2019-12-29 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID,(select max(d) from (select Date1 d uninon select Date2 d) as t) as MaxDate
from MyTable
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.